# Kendo UI Grid Grouping with Aggregate: Use aggregate value of another column in Group header?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to use the aggregate value in another column (not the grouping column) in grouping header. For example, here is the demo from Kendo:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates

It aggregate the Units On Order for Units In Stock. I want to show the Average 14 in grouping header (besides Count: 5). Is it possible?

[image]

I tried to use template in header,

```
groupHeaderTemplate: "Units In Stock: #=value# (#=getAverage(data)# / #=count#)"
```

Then in getAverage(), I calculated the value based on data.

```
var aggregates = ds.aggregates();
var averaged = aggregates.UnitsOnOrder.average;
```

However, the average is the average of all rows, not the data within the group.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the average in `data.aggregates`, which will contain the aggregates for the relevant group:

```
groupHeaderTemplate: "Units In Stock: #= value # (Count: #= count#)" +  
                     "(avg: #= aggregates.UnitsOnOrder.average #)"
```

([demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/eCoWU))

Comment: I have also same issue but still it is doing sum of all rows of grid not for particular group..